# Detecting when socket gets disconnected via sock.recv and socket.timeout

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I have this function to detect state of socket connection (connected or disconnected):

```
def connection_status(self):

        try:

            sock.settimeout(2)
            connection_status = sock.recv(32)
            print("Status: Connected")
            self.label_connection_status['text'] = 'Status: Connected'
            self.label_connection_status['fg'] = 'green'

        except socket.timeout:

            connection_status = ""
            print("Status: Disconnected")
            self.label_connection_status['text'] = 'Status: Disconnected'
            self.label_connection_status['fg'] = 'red'

        self.master.after(3000, self.connection_status)
```

But there is a problem with it. When I connects to server (in my case Samsung TV, its remote control application), it few times spam "Status: Connected", but after some seconds it changes to "Status: Disconnected" (but is still connected...), and if I send some data to the server (Samsung TV), it again changes to "Connected" and after few seconds it again changes to "Disconnected". And id I stop the server (Samsung TV), it only outputs "Status: Connected"!

Comment: Does your TV constantly stream 32 bytes every 3 seconds or less?

Comment: @BryanOakley I dont clearly know, but if I set less bytes it outputs "Status: Connected" more higher time, so.. yea, problem could be on TV, but how adapt to TV the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you confusing recv() with connection/disconnection? recv() interrupted by timeout simply means there was no data received during specified time frame, but by no means it indicates a disconnection! On the contrary, graceful disconnection will NOT manifest itself as a timeout on recv(), instead, it would be a return from recv() with approriate status, indicating a disconnecting event.

Comment: so how to check if connection is dead?!

Comment: @PepinCZ, this depends on what do you mean by 'dead connection'.

Comment: Thats easy, if the TV turend off or gets disconnected from WIFI network, or PC gets disconnected.

Comment: Those are actually different events. TV turned off gracefully (not by meaning of unplugging it) will with any luck include a graceful connection shutdown. In this case, like I said, you will see immediate return from recv() with a code indicating connection closure. PC gets disconnected from network will likely do the same for you, because network stack is expected to understand network disconnection. TV disconnected from WiFi would be a gray area, and in this case you are not likely to see disconnection. You will have to rely on some extended time without any activity.

Comment: In the latter case, I suggest immediate explicit disconnect followed by reconnection attempt to clarify the situation. If connection fails, it is indeed a network disconnection event, TV blow up or something of the sorts. Successfull connection simply indicates there was legitimate data transmission hiatus.